# How to test a recycler view adapter in Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-recyclerview

Can someone help me test this recycler view adapter? I wan't to make a local unit test, but doesn't really know how to begin?
Following is my recyclerViewAdapter class:

```
 public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {
    private List<TasksTask> task;
    protected Context context;
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<TasksTask> task) {
        this.task = task;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerViewHolders viewHolder = null;
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.to_do_list, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView, task);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.categoryTitle.setText(task.get(position).getTask());

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.task.size();
    }}
```

And here is my recyclerViewHolder class:

```
public class RecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private static final String TAG = RecyclerViewHolders.class.getSimpleName();
    public TextView categoryTitle;
    public ImageView deleteIcon;
    private List<TasksTask> taskObject;


    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    public RecyclerViewHolders(final View itemView, final List<TasksTask> taskObject) {
        super(itemView);
        this.taskObject = taskObject;
        categoryTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        deleteIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_delete);

        deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String taskTitle = taskObject.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTask();
                mDatabase.child("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("Tasks").child(taskTitle).removeValue();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I've been wondering that myself and have found this:
https://chelseatroy.com/2015/09/27/android-examples-a-test-driven-recyclerview/
there are example tests for each adapter method in there, hope that helps